# UV Distortions while using edge slide

Tags: uv

I am making 3D models for Unreal Engine in blender. I think it can be important becaus I have a world scale set to 0.01. I have a building image, and I would like to move loop cuts, but it creates some weird UV distortions. On the image there is just a simple plane with 4 verticies, and I am trying to add and move a loop cut. What may be the problem? Thanks[image]

Here's how to (possibly) reproduce it.

1. I set Unit Scale to 0.01, and units to metric.
2. I change Clip start and clip end values to 1 cm and 1 km (but I do not think it actualy matters)
3. I create a plane and apply a texture
4. I scale the plane in edit mode 10 times (when it is small, the problem usualy does not occur)
5. I add a loop cut, and move it around

Comment: UVs shouldn't be distorted as long as you enable Correct UVs option in the Edge Slide operator settings.

Comment: Yes, I have Correct UVs enabled, and it usually works. I think that there may be something wrong with a scale I am working with. It is set to 0.01, because I will use those models in Unreal Engine later.

Comment: Can't replicate that but my version isn't the newest. Anyway for export it should be possible to set Length to any other option like Centimeters in the Units rollout and then set the Unit Scale back to 1. Or when exporting to fbx change the Scale in the export options instead of messing up with scale factors in the scene

Comment: It would work, but for meshes with a bone structure and animations it is impossible to import them to Unreal Engine without problems.

Comment: In the UV editor do you have UV Sync Selection enabled? Have a look what is happening in the UV editor as you slide the edge in the 3D viewport. The texture is only being distorted along the X axis (left to right). The texture is appearing as if you were sliding that edge in the UV space ! BTW when edge sliding don't use the simple G command , use the G G command which will hold the slide along the correct axis.

Comment: It occurs both with UV Sync enabled and disabled. It distorts from left to right when I add a "horizontal" cut, and from up to down when I add a "vertical" cut. And yes, I am using G G to slide edge.

Comment: Usually when you use the G G edge slide command we see a yellow line at one end of the edge which indicates the direction of slide. Not seeing that in your .gif.

Comment: I think that this yellow line shows only when you press "E" during edge sliding. There is also yellow line when you slide a vertex. I assure you that I use "G G". Also - even if I would use G, that kind of distortions should never occur.